# java regex: finding a pattern of one character s follows by 5 digits range 0-9

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use matches("regex") to throw an exception, but I always get wrong. Is there a way to match the pattern in the title? For example, the pattern should be "s98340" or "s12345". There is only one character at the beginning and followed by any 5 digits.
To catch an exception:

```
try{
        if(originalLocation.length() != 6 && originalLocation.matches("s[0-9]{5}"))
            throw new IllegalOriginalLocationException("Original Location is invalid.");
    }
    catch(IllegalOriginalLocationException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

When I set String sr = "s4a234", the exception is not caught.

Comment: Show more code and the *specific* error you're getting.

Comment: The pattern is correct, `s.matches("s[0-9]{5}")` will only return true if the string starts with `s` and then has exactly 5 digits.

Comment: seems like you want to use `find` with `pattern and matcher`

Comment: `s4a234` has 6 chars, no exception will be thrown

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! I have already fixed the problem. That's helpful.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I delete originalLocation.length() != 6, then it work.

Comment: I posted an answer, please consider accepting since it worked and upvoting (if it proved helpful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `s98340` like strings to your method, the `originalLocation.length() != 6` condition returns false, thus, you get the current behavior.

Since the regex already matches a 6-char only string, it is enough to remove that condition:

```
try {
   if(originalLocation.matches("s[0-9]{5}"))
      throw new IllegalOriginalLocationException("Original Location is invalid.");
}
catch(IllegalOriginalLocationException ex) {
   System.out.println(ex);
}
```

The `originalLocation.matches("s[0-9]{5}")` line makes sure that the string starts with `s` and then has exactly 5 ASCII digits. Remember that the patterns inside `.matches()` are anchored at both start and end of string by default.

Answer (score 0):

intenta con lo siguiente :
try {
    if(!originalLocation.matches("**^[a-zA-Z]\d\d\d\d\d**"))
      ...

[a-zA-Z] lower or upper
[a-z] lower only

I'm test with  "s4a234"
and "a12345" and success!